# Taking the limit of $n(e^{-1/n}-1)$ as $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus

The form is infinity times zero and that is indeterminate which means I need to use L'Hospital's rule, but I have tried to do that but every time I would find another indeterminate form.  How can I use sneaky algebra or sneaky replacements to find the answer?

Comment: is this your limit? $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n(e^{-1/n}-1)$$

Comment: Yes it is my limit.

Answer (score 6):

By the verys definition of derivative, this limit equals $f'(0)$ where $f(x)=e^{-x}$: Note that $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=n(e^{-1/n}-1)$ if $h=\frac1n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: try expanding $e^{-1/n}$ as a power series: $$e^{-1/n}=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{n^2}+ \dots=1-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-2}) .$$

Answer (score 1):

recall $$e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$$as $x\to0$ hence$$e^{-1/n}=1-1/n+O(1/n^2)$$ as $n\to\infty$ and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(e^{-1/n}-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(-1/n+O(1/n^2))=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1+O(1/n))=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in general $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\alpha}=\log x$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Sure. Typo.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's Rule is not my favourite approach, since a computation replaces insight about the behaviour of the function. But one cannot deny its usefulness. We do two L'Hospital's Rule calculations.

**Calculation 1:** We want to find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-1/n}-1}{1/n}.\tag{1}$$
Let $x=\frac{1}{n}$. As $n\to\infty$, $1/n\to 0^+$. So if 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\tag{2}$$
exists, then our limit does, and is the same.
Now use L'Hospital's Rule, taking the derivative of the top and bottom of (2), Since 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{-e^{-x}}{1}=-1,$$
our limit exists and is $-1$.

**Calculation 2:** This time, we deliberately do things in a suboptimal way, by finding
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^{-1/y}-1}{1/y}.$$
Take the derivative of top and bottom. So we want to find
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{(-1/y^2)(-e^{-1/y})}{(-1/y^2)}.$$
The above simplifies to 
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}(-e^{-1/y}),$$
which is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use L hospitals rule, if you have 0/0 or inf/inf form.
So, rewrite your expression as (e^[-1/n] - 1)/(1/n) and now use the rule

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips